# How to run operator ElSE?

Tags: python-3.x

Sorry for my English... I wrote a program that monitoring the network, if there is no connection, it launches another script to restart the modem.

```
import os
import schedule
import time
import pyautogui

def host():
    hostname = "10.0.0.21"
    response = os.system("ping "+hostname+" -n 1 ")
    if response == 0:
        return (host)
    else:
        os.system(r'c:/watchdog/k.bat'), pyautogui.press('F10')
host()
schedule.every(2).minutes.do(host)
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

But there is one problem: if out of 20 packets it pings at least once, the else statement does not work. I want to add a condition, if the loss (LOST) is 60% or more, else worked. How to implement it? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Parse through the response for the ```"(<value>% loss)"``` and extract it.

Comment: where in the code should I add "(<value>% loss)"?